# run a subscriber callback once using rospy.spin()

Tags: ros, rospy, header, spin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am sorry if I am not using the proper words when I refer to "run a callback function" from a subscriber while using rospy. I'm not sure I got the concept of keeping the nodes sleeping. However, this is not my question.

I want to make a logger node node which takes data from the first message received in a topic, and writes it as a header in a file. Then it will be storing the raw data as long as rospy.spin() says so. The problem is, I have not found an example of how to do this, or if there is such a function. All I can think about are pretty cluttered solutions, which take the time stamp and compares them in every message.

my question is, is there a way to call

```
rospy.Subscriber("Flow", OpticalFlow2D.msg.FrameFlow, callbackOF)
```

many times  and

```
rospy.Subscriber("Flow", OpticalFlow2D.msg.FrameFlow, callbackOFonce)
```

just on the first time, to write the header?

Many thanks,

Cristian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30490/run-a-subscriber-callback-once-using-rospy.spin()/) by [cduguet](https://answers.ros.org/users/1941/cduguet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 187 on 2012-03-26

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want a particular callback for a topic only to be run for the first message received, you can unsubscribe from within the callback after you've finished your processing. For example:

```
def cb_once(msg, subscriber):
    #do processing here
    subscriber.unregister()

sub_once = None
sub_once = rospy.Subscriber('my_topic,', MyType, cb_once, sub_once)
```

In your case, however, you could have a single callback, and just keep a flag around like `wrote_header`, which you can set to true after the first message was received so you only write the header once.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2012-03-27**:
The above may not be entirely correct. The callback args may have to be an iterable, so the line would be sub_once = rospy.Subscriber('my_topic,', MyType, cb_once, [sub_once])

**Comment by [Benjamin Blumer](https://answers.ros.org/users/3673/benjamin-blumer/) on 2014-06-10**:
Based on the upvotes, I'm guessing this works for others. For me though, cb_once is receiving a None, and I get the exception "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'unregister'".

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you!

I did it using a flag, because (I don't know why it doesn't work, because it usually does to me) the callback function does not get the argument sub_once, therefore throwing the error "cb_once needs exactly two arguments", and it is being given one
(I don't know why it is not passing the argument, and yes, sub_once is given after the callback function name just as you wrote it).

Anyway, with the flags the problem is solved.

Thank you!

---

Originally posted by [cduguet](https://answers.ros.org/users/1941/cduguet/) with karma: 187 on 2012-03-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Seanny123](https://answers.ros.org/users/8436/seanny123/) on 2013-11-20**:
Would you mind giving an example of how you accomplished this in code?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This: http://answers.ros.org/question/46613/rospy-how-do-you-unsubscribe-to-a-topic-from-within-the-callback/  solution works, at the cost of having to make the subscriber global.

---

Originally posted by [Benjamin Blumer](https://answers.ros.org/users/3673/benjamin-blumer/) with karma: 287 on 2014-06-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1